# How do I find the most recent "created_date" from the Ticket table for each user?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to set up a route where I can see the most recent "created_at" value for the user's cart. I will be using this information to set up a timer. Ex. If your cart is untouched for 15 minutes we empty it.

How can I query both the user and their highest value "created_at" from mySQL on the ticket table?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
router.get('/cart', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userData = await User.findByPk(req.session.user_id, {
      attributes: {
        exclude: ["password"]
      },
      include: [{model: Ticket,
        include: [Seat, {model: Showing, include: Production}]
      }],
    }); 

    const ticketData = await Ticket.findOne({
      attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('created_at'))]],
    group: ['id'],
    // raw: true,
});

    const user = userData.get({ plain: true })

    res.render('cart', {
      ...user,
      logged_in: true,
    })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
});
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: Ya, post the current MySQL query you're using to get the user and their `created_at` value.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query